# Lowercase to Uppercase and Uppercase to Lowercase in C

Tags: c, uppercase, lowercase

Does anyone would help me with this code ? The function needs to do like in topic is written. Is it ok ? What is more I need is to count the number of made changes. How to implement this one ?

```
int change(char *path){

FILE *f = fopen(path, "r");
if(f==NULL){
    printf("Error...");
    return -1;
}
int text, length;

    fscanf(f, "%s", &text);
    length = strlen(text);

 for(i = 0; i < length; ++i){
    if(islower(text[i]))
          {
          text[i] = toupper(text[i]);
          }
    if(isupper(text[i]))
    {
        text[i] = toslower(text[i]);
    }
fprintf(f,"%s",text);
fclose(f);
```

Comment: Are you talking about English symbols? Or do you consider difficult cases like with ß symbol in German.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%C3%9F

Comment: Yes, only english symbols :) But even if ... what should be added then ?

Comment: Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598569/toupper-tolower-locale-german

Of course, you can ignore the complexity of locale questions and hope that every incoming symbol will be from US-ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of changes, simply create a variable (`int count = 0`) and increment it with every change (`count++`).

```
int change(char *path){


    FILE *f = fopen(path, "r");

    if(f==NULL){
        printf("Error...");
        return -1;
    }

    int text, length;
    int count = 0;

    fscanf(f, "%s", &text);
    length = strlen(text);

    for(i = 0; i < length; ++i){
        if(islower(text[i]))
        {
            text[i] = toupper(text[i]);
            count++;
        }
        if(isupper(text[i]))
        {
            text[i] = tolower(text[i]);
            count++;

        }
    }

    fprintf(f,"%s",text);
    fclose(f);
 }
```

Comment: I see, already done it. But looking through this whole code...is it done written ? :)

Comment: @user9000 It was running too fast... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Right now your code will first try to change the text from lower case to upper case, and then if this succeeds change it back to lower case. I don't think that's what you want since you now have two cases, either it changes from lower to upper and back to lower or it doesn't change at all.

To track the changes we add a variabled "changes" which we initialize to zero.

Instead if you want to change the character to upper case if it's lower case and to lower case if it's upper case rewrite it like this:

```
if(islower(text[i])) {
    text[i] = toupper(text[i]);
    changes++;
} else if(isupper(text[i])) { 
    text[i] = tolower(text[i]);
    changes++;
}
```

There's also a spelling mistake, toslower(text[i]) but I assume you meant tolower(text[i])